# Golang data as interface{} panics

Tags: go, reflection

Gophers,

I'm trying to implement the reflect package of Go and really stuck on one thing.

context - I'm trying to call an API that returns - time.Time and some data in interface{}. This data could be either int/int64 or float32/float64 for the most part. I take the data in interface{} and further create a struct where I keep the interface{} data in interface as reflect promises quite a few fancy things that I could do with the interface

```
type dataStore struct {
   CreateTime time.Time
   Data interface{}
}
```

I then create a`map[string][]dataStore` to store the data from the API that I fetch.

I'm trying to do the following to get the Float64 values that I know are coming and I want to do some math on them:

```
x := map[string][]dataStore {}
ReadDatafromAPI(x) // I call the API to read the data into variable x

//Assume map["CA"][]dataStore{{2020-03-31 21:55:52.123456, 123.4567890123e10},}

fmt.Println(x["CA"][0].Data) // This prints the data 123.4567890123e10, no problem

fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(x["CA"][0].Data))// this prints reflect.Value

va := reflect.ValueOf(x["CA"][0].Data) 

fmt.Println(va.(float64)) // panic: interface conversion: interface {} is reflect.Value, not float64

fmt.Println(va.Interface()) // prints 123.4567890123e10
fmt.Println(va.Kind()) // prints struct
fmt.Println(va.NumField()) // prints 2 and I can fetch the fields using Field(0) and Field(1) -- the data doesn't make sense to me. not sure if those are pointers or what
```

I have just one objective - to fetch float64 as float64 and int as int. Meaning use reflect the way it is supposed to be used.

any insight would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

Folks - thanks for all the answers and pointers. I appreciate this! Looks like I still get reflect.Value as the type and not float64/32 as expected. See below:

```
switch flt := x["CA"][0].Data.(type) {
case float64:
        fmt.Println("Data is float64 -> ", flt)
    fmt.Printf("Type for flt is %T -> ", flt)
case float32:
        fmt.Println("Data is float32 -> ", flt)
    fmt.Printf("Type for flt is %T -> ", flt)
default:
    fmt.Println("Its default!")
    fmt.Printf("Type for flt is %T -> ", flt) // I always get here with reflect.Value as the Type. Never a float64 which is the value store without any question
}


if nflt, ok := x["CA"][0].Data.(float64); ok {
    fmt.Println("nflt is float64")
} else {
    fmt.Println("nflt is not float64) // I always get to Else
}
```

Comment: Read https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 ff. (Or the whole Tour.)

Comment: You don't need reflect if you are just trying to extract `float64` and `int` types. Use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements). But as Volker has said, doing the tour is probably worth while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need reflection to convert an interface to one of the known types. You need type assertions or a type switch:

```
if flt, ok:=data.(float64); ok {
   // flt is float64
}
if i, ok:=data.(int); ok {
   // i is int
}
```

Or:

```
switch k:=data.(type) {
  case float64:
     // Here, k is float64
  case int:
     // Here, k is int
}
```

Comment: I've added my observation based on what I tried. thanks and PTAL

Comment: What does ReadDataFromAPI do? Looks like you have a reflect.Value there. You might also try type switch on `x["CA"][0].Data.Interface()`, but I suspect the culprit is your readData function.

Comment: Isn’t reflect.Value some value in itself as against literal reflect.Value? When I look up the type from the API call it does show up as reflect.Value. What the heck is reflect.Value?

Comment: `reflect.Value` is a reflection wrapper around a value. The actual value contained in it is `value.Interface()`

Comment: Hey! so I was collecting data from my API as-is which was of type interface{} I changed that to .Interface() while collecting it into my data structure. And now I'm able to get float64 and int in their intended forms. Thanks to you and everyone else who commented and posted pointers. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use a two-value [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get the value without panicking:

```
  d, ok := (x["CA"][0].Data.(float64)
  if ok {
     // it's a float64, do something with d.
  }
```

or use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches):

```
 switch d := x["CA"][0].Data.(type) {
 case int:
     // d is an int
 case float64:
     // d is a float64
 ... and other types as needed
 default:
     // handle unexpected type
 }
```

Comment: `x["CA"][0].Data.(float64).(type)` <-- why do you have `(float64)` here?

Comment: @zerkms It was there because of a copy paste error.  I corrected the answer. The syntax in the original version of my answer is not supported by the language,  I am sorry that I caused some confusion.

Comment: Hey there: I tried type switch as you suggested and I still get reflect.Value as the value without using the reflect Package: